# Why I can't get position of all items in my ListView?

Tags: java, android

My problem is, I have listView with contacts, then I'm using

```
onItemClickListener and Object obj = lImenik.getItemAtPosition(position); 
String tmp = obj.toString();
```

to get position of clicked item. That works fine for visible items.

But the problem is when I scroll little down and click on item which wasn't visible in the first place and try to get that position, I don't get it. Do I have to load differently?

for example:

```
        lImenik.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Object obj = lImenik.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String tmp = obj.toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, tmp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```